# How to show images in slide style in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, slider

I have some images, and I want show them in a slide style. I use `QGraphicsScene` to display image, I try to call `Sleep` between I load image into scene, but it doesn't work, actually, When I put this `Sleep` function (`#include <windows.h>`) in my code, I even can not see the the GUI windows. Anyway, I think there must be a better way, so , how can I do this? Another thing is I want use left key to control slide play, I mean when I press left arrow, it goes to next image.

Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: By slide style do you want to do animations? In other words, the new image ''slides in'' on top of the previous image. Or do you just want a new image to appear when you hit the left or right key? Or do you want some kind of tiled layout and when you click on an image it becomes full screen? Also, why specifically do you need the Sleep function? Some code may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Qt anyway, I would create a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html#details) as a member of your class and connect its `timeout()` signal to your own slot, e.g. `showNextSlide()`.

If you use any kind of sleep() function, the whole GUI thread will sleep, i.e. painting etc will not be performed before the sleep() is done.

Considering the left key, you can reimplement [QObject::eventFilter()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter) in the widget that usually has the focus. (Either inherit from that class or use `installEventFilter`)

Comment: Great, thank you for the suggestion and your answer to the sleep issue. :)